# How to create a folder inside the resource folder in SpringBoot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a SpringBoot app where I read a folder of the resource folder of the app. but I would like to know if it is possible also to create a folder **in the resource folder**

```
File folderFrom = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:icons/svg/white/");
```

something like

```
File folderTo = ResourceUtils.createFolder("classpath:icons/svg/black/");
```

I trying to do it from Eclipse:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SvgManagerApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SvgManagerApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {      
      ..
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you run your Spring Boot App as JAR?

Comment: First, we need to make sure... is your resource folder *guaranteed* to be a directory on the file system (vs content from a jar/war)?  Otherwise you might spend a lot of time building something that works while you're developing it, but then fails once you wrap it up to deploy it in production.  If these files are actually data that your application will work on, consider either coming up with a way to save it in the database, or have your platform provide a file system folder path as configuration data that you can then just use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `java.utils` to create a folder inside the resource directory

```
new File("/path/directory").mkdirs();
```

"directory" is the name for the folder you want to create

Answer (score -1):

you can get the root of the classpath from `new ClassPathResource(".").getFile().getPath()` and after that you can append the folder name that you want. after Make the File object by using that full path. and then you can create a folder as you want in the class path.

```java
File txtFile = new File(new ClassPathResource(".").getFile().getPath()+"/tmp");
if (!txtFile.exists()) {
     txtFile.mkdirs();
}
```